# jQuery failing on WordPress website

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress powered site that is failing to load its jQuery library properly. I am not sure where to look as I have worked mostly with Drupal and Laravel.

I get the following error messages:

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`
`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).directory is not a function`
`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).unslider is not a function`

The issue seems to be coming from `?code=23` which is in reference to the URL parameter: `/property/?code=23`

I realize this isn't much help in solving the issue, but perhaps there is some direction I should generally be looking in for troubleshooting jQuery in WordPress.

Comment: How/where are you including jQuery in your theme?

Comment: "$ is not a function" usually means that jQuery hasn't loaded yet or that you're referencing the jQuery object (represented as a $) outside of the allowed scope.

Comment: @fubar that's the thing, I don't think it is being included in the theme, is there somewhere else it could be pulled through from?

Comment: I believe it is coming in from a file called script-loader.php `$scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4' );
`

Comment: Then `$scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4' );`

Answer (score 0):

it was a conflict with a Third Party trying to bring in its own version of jquery.

Comment: Others may find it helpful if you state how you solved the problem, rather than just the cause.

Comment: Well we use a third party plugin from our other company, its a booking widget of sorts and can bring in its own version of jquery, but this is optional so I decided to turn it off. As you could assume it was trying to load 2 version of jquery on one page.

Answer (score 0):

try to use below jquery on above of your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```